# Find angle from its sine?

Tags: trigonometry

How can I find the actual value of an angle if I know the value of its sine?

Supposing that the angle I am looking for is named as $\theta$, what's it's value if $\sin(\theta)=0.719$?

Comment: There are infinitely many solutions without further restrictions.

Comment: So I saw somewhere that for `sin(θ)=0.719`, `θ` is 46 degrees. How did they find that? @AndrewChin

Comment: Seems like there's an answer below for you.  $\sin^{-1} x$ or $\arcsin x$ is the inverse function of $\sin x$ and is used to solve for $x$ in a trigonometric equation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The function you're looking for is called $\sin^{-1}(x)$. Answering your question,
$$\theta = \sin^{-1}(0.695) \approx 0.768 \space rad$$

since $\sin(x)$ is a periodic function, the value will repeat itself. In these cases, it is solved by using a trigonometric equation. The general solution of the above equation is 
$$\theta = n\pi + (-1)^n\sin^{-1}(0.695), \space n \in Z$$

These can be found in any high school maths textbook as well.

Comment: BUT: the periodicity of $\sin$ doesn't explain why $136^\circ$ is another solution between $0^\circ$ and $360^\circ$.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe I'm unable to understand.. 136° is a solution for what?

Comment: Oops, my fault. The other solution for $\sin(x)=0.719$ is $180-46=134$ instead, which isn't explained by periodicity.